# Can't get the data.success in jQuery,why?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, servlets

I send a data from servlet to jq.I can get the data as the log show below.But I can't get the value of the data [data.success](/questions/tagged/data.success).Why?

I have tried to add the "json" in the post,it dosen't work.

the servlet

```
PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();  
out.write("{"+"success"+":"+"1"+"}");
```

the js

```
$.post("Register",json,function(data){
                if(data.success){
                    console.log(data);
                    console.log(data.success);
                    layer.msg("login！", {icon: 7});
                    window.location.href = "login.html";
                } else {
                    console.log(data);
                    console.log(data.success);
                    layer.msg("the username exist!", {icon: 7});
                }
            }).fail(function(data){
                layer.msg("something wrong", {icon: 7});
            });
```

the console of chrome

```
{success:1}
undefined
```

Comment: That's because yours isn't valid JSON. JSON keys must be wrapped in double quotes, so your output should be `{"success":1}` instead. Also make sure to pass the correct `Content-Type` header.

Comment: @BackSlash BackSlash,it work.Thank  a lot.